# When I try to use command blocks in Minecraft is there a way to make them not show feedback in chat?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

So when I want to use a command block without other people seeing the feedback in chat I don’t know how to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can turn off command block feedback with this command:

```
/gamerule commandBlockOutput false
```

It will turn off all command block feedback for all players, so nobody will be able to see the command block feedback in chat.